# Google AutoCompleteService returns place with ID not known to PlacesService

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I'm having problems with PlacesService.getDetails by "place id" for a result from AutoCompleteService.getPlacePredictions which returns these ids.

Here's my code (also at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simoneau/cu2qtc0x/9/)):

```javascript
function initService() {
  var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(window.document.createElement('div'));
  var autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

  var showAddress = function(input) {
    autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({ input }, displayTopSuggestion);
  }

  var displayTopSuggestion = function(predictions) {
    var placeId = predictions[0].place_id;
    placesService.getDetails({
      placeId: placeId
    }, function(place, status) {
      console.log(placeId + ": " + status);
    });
  }

  showAddress('401 Park Drive, Boston, MA');
  showAddress('120 Wall Street, New York, NY');
}
```

This displays "OK" for the first one (cool) and "NOT FOUND" for the second one (confusing):

```
ChIJdd3kdPR544kRllG3JcXaViQ: OK
ChIJq7N18T1awokRXtu1sjDO7Jw: NOT_FOUND
```

That is, the PlacesService doesn't know the placeId returned in the results from the AutocompleteService.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: I get status OK for both ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cu2qtc0x/4/))

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @geocodezip. Here's what I get from your fiddle:

    ChIJdd3kdPR544kRllG3JcXaViQ
    ChIJq7N18T1awokRXtu1sjDO7Jw
    status=OK, address=401 Park Dr, Boston, MA 02215, USA
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatted_address' of null

Comment: I get:
ChIJdd3kdPR544kRllG3JcXaViQ
EjsxMjAgV2FsbCBTdHJlZXQsIFN0YXRlbiBJc2xhbmQsIE5ldyBZb3JrLCBOWSwgVW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcw
status=OK, address=120 Wall St, Staten Island, NY 10301, USA
status=OK, address=401 Park Dr, Boston, MA 02215, USA
perhaps you are connected to a different server that isn't consistent (yet).

Comment: @geocodezip It does look to be context-dependent.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete#try-it-yourself

If I try this address, typing "120 Wall Street, New York, NY" and clicking on it in the drop-down, the first time it works (when we've started in Sydney). If I try the same thing a second time (after we've moved to NY), I get a "no details available" dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it may have been a manifestation of a transient issue in the Maps APIs: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63069427

Comment: Yes, the issue i filed received a similar response:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62845250